# Copied Textbox is not visible in IDE

Tags: vb.net, textbox, ide, visual-studio-2019

[image]

I have just upgraded to Windows 10 and VS 2019 from Windows 7 and VS 2017. In this question I am refering to the images above (Images 1 to 5). During development of a VB.Net App I needed several text boxes so I added one from the toolbox (image 1) then copied the newly added textbox and pasted it onto the form (image 2) but the newly pasted textbox was not visible (image 3). It was certainly there and should have been visible (see properties list above) and I could select it from the properties drop down list of controls but not by clicking on the form. When I ran the App the textbox was there in full view as expected. In the IDE I changed the border to "None" (image 4) and the textbox became visible. I then changed the border back to Fixed 3D and the texbox was still visible as I expected it to be from the start (image 5). I did a fairly thorough search for this issue but found nothing so I suspect it's something to do with my setup here or I would have expected many reports about this. Any ideas anyone? Thanks.

Comment: I could not reproduce this error. I copied and pasted with the context menu (right click menu)

Comment: Try repairing you installation. On your Windows Start Menu select the Visual Studio Installer. Click the Repair button.

Comment: Thanks Mary. Reinstalling, repairing, etc. take so long that they are always a last ditch option for me but since you were unable to replicate the issue I took your advice and opened the installer. There was a new update available which I thought might have a similar effect to the repair option and sure enough the long wait for the update to install was worth it. My text boxes are now behaving themselves. Thanks again.